# textbox multiline view text in a div

Tags: c#, multiline

I have a textbox multiline for insert text in my db.
This text is viewed in a div, but without newlines.

How can I view the newline in my text?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your text inside `<div><pre>... text ...</pre></div>`. [pre](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_pre.asp) tag preserves line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
myText = myText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

to replace newline characters with proper HTML line-breaks.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: thank but i receive this error
'System.Environment' does not contain a definition for 'Newline'

Comment: Woops, that's a typo. It's Environment.NewLine - with an upper case L.